# Brother MFC-295CN Scanner

Tags: drivers, command-line, scanning

I have managed to add my MFC-295CN printer to my Ubuntu 11.04 desktop. However, I need some help adding the scanner.
from the Brother website I am instructed to install the driver
step 4-3) Command (for dpkg)

`# dpkg  -i  --force-all  (scanner-drivername)`

and the example given is:

```
dpkg -i brscan-skey-0.2.1-1.i386.deb 
Selecting previously deselected package brscan-skey.
(Reading database ... 89058 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking brscan-skey (from brscan-skey-0.2.1-1.i386.deb) ...
Setting up brscan-skey (0.2.1-1) ...
```

With terminal I can add PPA's and remove programs but this is very confusing to me. Do I write the '#'? do I need to type 'sudo'? 
FYI I need to download the brscan3 driver. Please help me with this, once I get this I won't need Windows 7 really anymore, being able to scan from Ubuntu would be a huge win.

Thank you,

Dustin

Comment: The '#' is a root prompt and you need to omit that.And yes you need 'sudo'

Answer (score 3):

Ok here is how I got my MFC-295CN scanner working.
I downloaded the drivers, prerequisites, brscan3 ect and installed using software centre. I also installed Xsane. Scanning did not work with Xsane and simple scan. 
So I edited the rules.

1. Open `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` file.
2. Add the following two lines to the end of the device list. (Before the line "# The following rule will disable ..."):

   ```
   # Brother scanners
   ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
   ```
3. Restart the OS.

But to edit it, you have to use terminal.
like this: `gksudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules`

This is how to get your MFC-295CN scanner to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have downloaded your file and will show you how I do it:

After accepting this page:

[image]

The download starts and when it finishes at the bottom I click the little arrow next to the file and choose 'open'. Since it is a DEB my system takes over by issuing Ubuntu software Center to install it:

[image]

Hit `install` and it should work on your system.

No need to mess around with command line (that's oldskool ;) ).

<sub>I did not actually install it since I do not need this driver</sub>