# Getting my brother MFC-J825DW working as a network scanner

Tags: printing, scanner, brother

I've been attempting to set up my new brother multi-function device to work as a printer and scanner using the following steps.  It is connected to the network as a LAN device, not directly connected to my ubuntu machine.

1. Search [Brother support](http://support.brother.com) for the MFC-J825DW and download the deb packages for the lpr driver and cupswrapper drivers.
2. Follow install instructions for each driver, making sure you have all required packages installed (`ia32-libs` or `lib32stdc++` if using 64bit ubuntu for example).

After this point I was able to successfully perform a test print, so the printer part is working.  So far I haven't had much luck getting the scanner working.  This is what I've tried:

1. Download the brscan4 and scan-key-tool deb packages from brother support as above.
2. Followed the instructions for installing these ensure you have all requried packages installed (such as `sane-utils`).

However when I tried to scan it detects no scanner.

I then tried the solution offered in [this answer to a question](https://askubuntu.com/a/48389/18643) based on a similar brother printer, but no luck.  I must have made a mistake somewhere along the line.  Does anyone have any ideas what I can try to find out what?  Or should I uninstall everything and start again from the beginning?

Comment: Did you copy the libs: http://askubuntu.com/a/81078/3940

Comment: @Takkat I shouldn't need to do that as I'm not on a 64bit machine as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Takkat Thanks for that hint, made my MFC-465CN get recognized as a scanner! Should be the answer to the problem.

Comment: @rearlight: well, it already is an answer on the site - glad it helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated answer for January 2019**

There is a new single `deb` installer package on the Brother website that installs both printer and scanner drivers. This makes installation much easier.

1. Download the 'Driver install tool`.
2. Open bash terminal and navigate to download folder.
3. Unzip the file...

   ```
   gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1.gz
   ```

(version number will probably change, so watch for that).

4. Change to superuser or use `sudo` for the following commands:

   ```
   bash linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-* MFC-J825DW
   ```
5. Agree to prompts and select to use ip address (11 or I when I did it) , then enter the printers ip address when prompted. You can find the address on the printers touch screen display from the 'network' menu if you don't know it.

---

**Old answer, which concerned what to do if you entered the wrong IP address, however it is probably outdated and I suggest trying to rerun the Driver install tool and re-entering the ip address again when prompted.**

I think this is a case of only being stuck until you ask for help.  Soon after posting this I decided to check the ip addesses of the printer and scanner.  Sure enough I'd entered a different ip for each one somehow.  Since the printer worked and the scanner didn't, I made the assumption that the scanner had the wrong one.

To correct this I had to enter the following line at the command prompt:

```
brsaneconfig4 -r SCANNER
```

This command removed the scanner with the incorrect ip address.  Then I simply added it back again, making sure the ip address was right this time.

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name=SCANNER model=MFC-J825DW ip=192.168.3.3
```

*Note: You should probably set the scanner up to a fixed ip in the router, otherwise you may have problems later on when it gets assigned a different ip when the router is reset.*

Comment: AntonChanning solution worked for the MFC-J870DW also

Comment: @Hatem I suspect this solution works for all models of Brother scanners supported by brsaneconfig4.