# Installing Brother MFC-J825DW printer

Tags: printing, brother

I have a client who I had to switch to Ubuntu after another Linux distro stopped working for her.  I got her working on Ubuntu 14.04 as her laptop is older.  All works fine - except for printing.

She has a Brother MFC-J825DW printer that worked fine with her old Linux (Puppy).  But I cannot get the $#@! thing to work with Ubuntu!

I searched for instructions, and followed them (I think) correctly, but it didn't work.  Here are the steps I took:

- With both the computer and printer turned on, I plugged the USB cord from the printer into the computer.
- When I did the above I did not get an option to select the model of the printer.  Instead, I got the option to **Enter URL** -  obviously wrong, as this is a USB connection.  The >only< other option I got was **Network Printer** - also wrong for the same reason.  No third option for USB was visible.

I also tried 2 different USB cords - but no change.

I've played a bit with Ubuntu, but could really use some advice from more experienced users.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145680/getting-my-brother-mfc-j825dw-working-as-a-network-scanner

Answer (score 0):

Some Brother printers require a little more work than most other printers.  Brother has been good about providing installation tools that usually work well.  I believe [this is the page](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj825dw_all&os=128) you will need.

You have to run the downloaded tool as `sudo`. Unfortunately I am not near any of my Ubuntu systems at the moment and cannot tell you what other prompts you may need to answer, but I am sure you will need to enter your printer model.

Comment: can you update this at all?