# Printer Brother DCP-7065DCN worked but not the scanner in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: scanner

I am new to Linux and just done installed Ubuntu 16.04. I have the local USB printer Brother DCP-7065 DCN and it worked fine in the Ubuntu. However, the Simple Scanner apps does not see the scanner. Steps I took so far.

Downloaded 64 bit scanner drivers `brscan4-0.4.2-1.amd64.deb`, `brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb` and `brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb`. I installed all of them.

```
sudo dpkg  -i  --force-all brscan4-0.4.2-1.amd64.deb
sudo dpkg  -i  --force-all brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb
```

No errors.

I ran `dpkg  -l  |  grep  Brother`:

```
ii  brscan-skey                            0.2.4-1                                                     amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan4                                    0.4.2-1                                                     amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                     3-5~ubuntu1                                                 amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                      1.4-1                                                       amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

I check the `config.dll` file and see `brother4` listed in there.

I ran `sane-find-scanner` and it said

```
# No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
# you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.
```

"Unable to connect scanner" message came up when I used Simple scanner .

What I have missed? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this printer before, I only used the debs on the brother's page:

http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=es&prod=dcp7065dn_all&os=128&flang=English

Look for Scanner Drivers you need 32 or 64bit.

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution from this post and it worked. The only thing I changed was set ip to 0.0.0.0 although this is local USB printer.

brsaneconfig4 -a name=SCANNER model=DCP-7065DCN ip=0.0.0.0

[Getting my brother MFC-J825DW working as a network scanner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145680/getting-my-brother-mfc-j825dw-working-as-a-network-scanner?rq=1)